# Need help importing a text file into byte[] for JDK 6

Tags: java, encoding, decode

This is the code I am using that retrieves data from a letter.txt file

```
File file = new File("/Users/Shiv/Eclipse/CPS3498/letter.txt");
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuffer.append(line);
                stringBuffer.append("\n");
            }
            fileReader.close();
```

I am trying to put the contents of letter.txt into this.

```
        byte[] text = "No body can see me".getBytes();
```

Comment: @flkes I looked at the link but that only works in JDK 7 and 8. I need to get it to work in JDK 6 as per my assignment

Comment: Add that to the title

Comment: @flkes sorry about that. I just added it to the title.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
File file = new File("/Users/Shiv/Eclipse/CPS3498/letter.txt");
final byte[] text;
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
try
{
    FileChannel fc = fis.getChannel();
    long size = fc.size();
    if (size > Integer.MAX_VALUE)
    {
        throw new IllegalStateException("File too large");
    }
    text = new byte[(int) size];
    fc.read(ByteBuffer.wrap(text));
}
finally
{
    fis.close();
}
System.out.println(text.length);
```